# How to get data sent by cloud telephony service using django url?

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I am planning to use cloud telephony to get sms data sent over Http. Service provider say this is how the format would be

```
http://domainname/location?mobilenumber=XXXXX&message=XXXXX&receivedon=MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS AM/PM
```

How should i process this url. Is it just that i have to write an url pattern like this below?

```
url(r'^/location/(P?<mobilenumber>)\d+/(P?<message>)\w+P?<receicedon>)\d+$',app.project.views.widget,name='swidget')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using url as:

```
url(r'^/location/',your_view,name='swidget')
```

When you use **GET parametes** like `www.host.com/end_point/?message=value&something=value2` you don't have to set them in the url, instead just use `url(r'^/end_point/, some_view)`

and view like

```
def your_view(request):
    mobilenumber = request.GET['mobilenumber']
    message = request.GET['message']
    receivedon = request.GET['receivedon']

    # Do what you need
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `Can I Serialize this data? using djangorest api.

Comment: sure @user3364535, take a look here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ you just have to create single class from **serializers.Serializer** with your required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a view for the path `/location`, and inside the view use the [`request.GET` dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) to see the parameters in the URL:

```
def location_view(request):
    mobilenumber = request.GET['mobilenumber']
    ...
```